# Gorilla websocket very slow when more than one client using it

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I made a small chatting application using gorilla websocket. When there is only one client, it's fast, as expected. But when I connect with another client, the chat takes maybe 3 seconds to update, even when hosted on my local machine.

Code for websocket:

```golang
var clients = make(map[*websocket.Conn]bool)
var broadcast = make(chan Message)
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{}
func main() {
    router.HandleFunc("/ws", handleConnections)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", router)
}
func handleConnections(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer ws.Close()
    clients[ws] = true
    for {
        var msg Message
        err := ws.ReadJSON(&msg)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error: %v", err)
            delete(clients, ws)
            break
        }
        broadcast <- msg
    }
}

func handleMessages() {
    for {
        msg := <-broadcast
        log.Println(msg)
        database, _ := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./database.db")
        statement, _ := database.Prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT, message TEXT, timestamp INTEGER)")
        statement.Exec()
        statement, _ = database.Prepare("INSERT INTO messages (username, message, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")
        statement.Exec(&msg.Username, &msg.Message, &msg.Timestamp)
        for client := range clients {
            err := client.WriteJSON(msg)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("error: %v", err)
                client.Close()
                delete(clients, client)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full code: https://github.com/mismaah-abdulla/Chatapp-Backend/blob/de8cc0eb88fa7f18b293bb0f2229368887c53adf/src/main.go

Comment: Things to fix in the application: 1) Open the database, create the table and prepare the statement outside the message loop. A setup function called from main is a good place to put this code.  2) Fix the data race on `clients`.

Comment: I fixed 1 but the problem still persists. I don't know what you mean by data race on clients. Full code: https://github.com/mismaah-abdulla/Chatapp-Backend/blob/091e684d04e6a0c17e18487bd324077deddef91f/src/main.go

Comment: Is the database write in `handleMessages` slow? 
 Does the loop in `handleMessages` get stuck on a slow client?   Data race: writes to `clients` in handle connections are concurrent with read in `handleMessages`.   I recommend starting with [gorilla's chat example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat).   It handles several issues that the code in the question does not.  Just sprinkle in the database stuff and you should be good to go.

Comment: I just checked the time it takes to run the database write in handleMessages. It takes either 0 or 5 seconds. It takes 5 seconds right after a new client connects to the websocket but a few mins (1-3) after that it's either 0 or 5 seconds randomly. Weird.

Comment: Is this question about why database writes are slow, not why websockets are slow?  If so, either edit or delete the question.

Comment: But it's not slow if there is only one client. So I assume it's not a database issue.

Comment: Determine where the code is slow.  Is `ws.ReadJSON(&msg)` slow to complete after the client sends a message?  Is the time to execute `client.WriteJSON(msg)` slow?  Time each invocation and log.  Is something in the client slow?   Also, fix the datarace.

Comment: try to increase broadcast channel capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the database was locked when trying to write. The fix is simple adding 
defer rows.Close() everytime a query was run.
For example:

```golang
func messages(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rows, _ := database.Query("SELECT username, message, timestamp FROM messages")
    defer rows.Close()
    var messages []Message
    for rows.Next() {
        var msg Message
        rows.Scan(&msg.Username, &msg.Message, &msg.Timestamp)
        messages = append(messages, msg)
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(messages)
}
```